# Independence of inverse system to define continuous cohomology for profinite groups

Tags: group-cohomology, profinite-groups

I have a problem concerning cohomology of profinite groups as it is defined e.g. in Gille's and Szamuely's "Central Simple Algebras and Galois Cohomology" on page 86.

For a profinite group $G=\varprojlim G_\alpha$ with maps $\phi_{\alpha\beta}:G_\beta\to G_\alpha$, they assume the $\phi$ to be surjective. That's not given by definition, but can be assumed without loss of generality by replacing $G_\alpha$ with $\pi_\alpha(G_\alpha)$, where $\pi_\alpha:G\to G_\alpha$ is the canonical projection. That's okay so far.
Then, the continuous cohomology groups are defined as the direct limit of the System $(H^i(G_\alpha, A^{U_\alpha}), \mathrm{Inf}_\alpha^\beta)$ with inflation maps.

My question then is: if I can write $G\cong\varprojlim G_i'$ as another inverse limit of finite groups, are the cohomology groups I get the same (up to isomorphism)? I don't see any argument in this case. 
I've found several other possibilities to define continuous cohomology groups for profinite groups that does not depend on the inverse limit, but here, I don't see any reason why this should be well-defined.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This definition is usually shown equivalent to the various other ones in most books like Wilson's book or Ribes and Zalesski

Comment: I would guess that they are not equivalent, if you only insist that $G\cong \lim_{\leftarrow}G_i'$ as a group. You need to insist that the isomorphism be bicontinuous with respect to the profinite topology. If that is the case, then there is a "biggest" representation of $G$ as a profinite limit, namely the limit over all finite dicrete (!) quotients of $G$ and the independence should be easy to prove.

Comment: Presumably this is what the op means.